# IWD One Page Checkout: Frontpage above checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

My frontpage design is using (1column.phtml) code below..
But checkout is using the same file, which is printing my frontpage about the checkout..
See image below code

**(1column.phtml):**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<body class="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('accordsettings/accordsettings_appearance/width'); echo $this->getBodyClass()?' '.$this->getBodyClass().'':'' ?>">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>      
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?> 
           <!-- Home Slider Block --> 
           <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('accord_home_slider_banner_block')->toHtml() ?>
<!-- Header block call -->
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('accord_header_block')->toHtml() ?>
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('accord_home_offer_banner_block')->toHtml() ?>
       <section class="main-col">  
          <article>             
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>               
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
          </article>
      </section> <!--main-col-->
<!-- Home Lastest Blog Block -->
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('accord_home_latest_blog_block')->toHtml() ?>
<!-- Static Banner Block -->
      <section><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('accord_static_banner_block')->toHtml() ?></section>
<!-- Logo Brand Block -->
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
      <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?> 

<!-- Home page newsletter -->
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml() ; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs to a third party module.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry, didn't know.. that i was dancing on the edge  here.... ill go kill my self now...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the content of `1column.phtml` and create a new file name it your own, like `onepage1column.phtml`,paste the content in it, place it on the same location where `1column.phtml` is and remove the blocks which you don't need and edit the layout xml file of iwd's onepage checkout and find the following code:

```
<reference name="root">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1columns.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

and replace it with following:

```
<reference name="root">
       <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/onepage1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

if you don't find the above code, then add the below one in the index tag of the module.